# Cannot evaluate string expression of a list to a list in Python (list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple - error)

Tags: python-3.x, eval

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
file = open("Modern Text List", "r").read()
print(file)

print(eval(file))
```

To change this text :

> [['List Of Modern Text'], ['Speaker', 'Dialogue'], ['FIRST WITCH',
>   'When should the three of us meet again? Will it be in thunder,
>   lightning, or rain?']][['List Of Modern Text'], ['Speaker',
>   'Dialogue'], ['FIRST WITCH', 'When should the three of us meet again?
>   Will it be in thunder,                                 lightning, or
>   rain?']][['List Of Modern Text'], ['Speaker', 'Dialogue'], ['FIRST
>   WITCH', 'When should the three of us meet again? Will it be in
>   thunder,                                 lightning, or rain?']][['List
>   Of Modern Text'], ['Speaker', 'Dialogue'], ['FIRST WITCH', 'When
>   should the three of us meet again? Will it be in thunder,
>   lightning, or rain?']]

to a python list.

But I get this error:

```
<ipython-input-46-695cb87082c4> in <module>()
     14 print(type(file))
     15 
---> 16 print(eval(file))

<string> in <module>()

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

In my JupyterNotebook.

The code was running fine yesterday. 
Doesn't seem to be working today.

I'm new in this, so please explain how to solve this. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:
I had been appending to the file.
Hence the text got repeated, and the structure changed. :p

Comment: @Frogboxe answering your own question is [explicitly encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here – editing the answer into the question is exactly the *wrong* approach.

Comment: Oh right, I dont know where I got that idea from. Never mind what I said then.